# What's the fastest way to draw a Hello World in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jvm

What's the **fastest** way to draw a Hello World on the screen using a GUI in Java:

1- by using the minimum number of classes.

2- with the least byte code executed

3- the JVM tweaks

so when I double click on the Jar file in Windows, the Hello World appears in no time (assuming the Runtime is not already loaded).

Comment: rt.jar is about 40 MB, so short of an SSD I don't think you can make it *instant*.

Comment: Interesting related article: http://java.sys-con.com/node/37060 (Hello World! in 70 bytes).

Comment: @BalusC, the OP is asking for a graphical version, the 70 bytes example will only write to console!

Comment: If you're looking for fast start-up time, consider some other language. Java has a lot of nice features but fast start-up is not one of them.

Comment: @medopal: I know, that's also why I didn't post it as an answer and explicitly mentioned "related". It involves hacking at bytecode level which is an interesting way to optimize the one and other more.

Comment: why is rt jar sooooo big.
My question is related to my little game. instead of a Hello World, I just want to create a raw canvas and draw on it using my own classes. Why should I load the full RT jar when I only need a few classes? Can Java be redesigned so you can break rt.jar in several much smaller jar and load only what's needed?

Comment: Only a fool asks for a computer program to execute "in no time".  Sorry if that is harsh, but its the truth: every program must execute instructions, and instructions take time to execute.  I once fought (successfully) to have the language "instantaneous" taken out of a contract I was going to enter into.

Comment: Fastest way to draw on a screen? With a marker I imagine ;)

Answer (score 10):

this is the fastest graphical Hello world i could get.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: lol that's the best answer! Never thought to do it like that.

Comment: you even get the icon on the message box as bonus :), actually as the guys in the comments said, the main libraries are not too small, so even the smallest application will need few seconds

Answer (score 3):

The [`SplashScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) class would be tough to beat as it can display an image even before JVM starts, though I'm not sure if it qualifies for a "GUI".

With an empty `main()` (which results in a 370-byte class file with Win XP JDK6), `java -splash:helloworld.png <class>` (or a jar) would run faster than you can blink.

Or you can use this trivial class to control how long you'll see the image:

```
public class DoNothing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int i = 1000;
        if( args != null && args.length > 0 )
            try{ i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); }
            catch( NumberFormatException ex ) {} 
        Thread.sleep(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're optimizing for runtime then pre-render an image with the text "Helo World" and then use Java to display it as an image. You can use `ImageIcon` to easily display an image.