# How to create an hello world in Java Swing? What is wrong in my code?

Tags: java, swing

I am studying Java Swing and I have some problem with the following simple code:

```
package com.techub.exeute;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       

        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Hello World !!!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        myLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 22));
        myLabel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        myLabel.setOpaque(true);
        myLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));

        frame.getContentPane().add(myLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
}
```

My idea is to create a **JFrame** object and insert into it an Hello World **JLabel** object settings some property.

I do it into the **main()** method. The problem is that when I execute the program I don't see anything !!! Why? What is wrong in my code?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Please no sarcasm...if I execute this code into Eclipse the Hello World do not appear to me !!!

Comment: Also, you should create swing components only in the event dispatch thread. See [concurrency in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: BTW: The best HelloWorld with java and swing is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429369/whats-the-fastest-way-to-draw-a-hello-world-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

to your code

See the steps to [Creating and Showing Java Swing Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You missed out #5

Answer (score 11):

You are creating the frame but you are not displaying it. Call

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

to display it.

Another thing: you should not manipulate GUI components in the main thread. Instead, create a new method for creating the frame and setting up the components, and run that method in the event dispatch thread, like in [the example from the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html):

```
import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldSwing {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining correct initialization in the EDT. I'm afraid I have done this wrong for years :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

call in your code.

As others mentioned you should not use the main `Thread` for gui operations. I suggest you should refer to the [official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html) of SWING, they are rather helpful and you'll see examples there for proper threading.

Answer (score 2):

keep this line in your method

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```