# What is the shortest way of an Java AWT HelloWorld example?

Tags: java, awt

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429369/whats-the-fastest-way-to-draw-a-hello-world-in-java) example uses Swing to render a message dialog. I wondered if there is a comparable solution using the AWT only. It should involve a minimum of classes/code. No applets please.

**Edit:** I know AWT is very old, but its for playing around and having fun.

**Edit2:**

So far I came up with such code from http://www.jan.newmarch.name/java/xadvisor/dialogs/dialogs.html:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class AWTHello extends Frame {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
      new AWTHello().show();
    }

    AWTHello() {
      add("Center", new InvokeDialog(this));
      pack();
    }
}

class InvokeDialog extends Button {
    Frame frame;

    InvokeDialog(Frame fr) {
      super("Show dialog");
      frame = fr;
    }

    public boolean action(Event evt, Object what) {
      Dialog d = new Dialog(frame, false);
      d.add("Center", new Label("Hello"));
      d.pack();
      d.show();
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `swingx` is a GUI toolkit, you mean that example uses Swing

Comment: AWT is Java 1.0, 1995 vintage stuff.  You should be using Swing.

Comment: @duffymo Swing is kind of 2005 vintage stuff ;-)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2429604/2970947) swing example is *very* short.

Comment: @AndréStannek - Swing built on top of AWT and officially superceded it in 1998, IIRC.

Comment: @duffymo I never said that AWT should be used instead of Swing. Just saying that Swing isn't really modern itself anymore. Even though it has no official successor.

Comment: @AndréStannek - Agreed, I didn't interpret your comment that way.  No official successor on desktop, because no one cares about desktop anymore.  All the action has moved to browser - web and mobile.

Comment: *"for playing around and having fun."*  You have a very odd idea of 'fun'.  See the `HelloWorldApplication` on [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/196500/32631) for 12 LOC (and my rave on why you should avoid both applets **and AWT**).

Comment: I recommend Eclipse SWT

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Window;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Dialog d = new Dialog(((Window)null),"Hello world!");
  d.setBounds(0, 0, 180, 70);
  d.add(new Label("Hello world!"));
  d.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ByteBit's solution is very short but will not close. With the anonymous class as 
[Mr. P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727039/mr-p) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21237840/6375113) I got this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AWTHello {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
      Frame f = new Frame( "Hello world!" );
      f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){ public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ){ System.exit( 0 ); } } );
      f.setSize( 300, 100 );
      f.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: show() is deprecated, overall I like what Mr. P suggested

Answer (score 3):

You should not use it but if you really want to try:

```
package awt;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f=new Frame("Hello World example of awt application");
        Label label1=new Label("Hello World", Label.CENTER);
        f.add(label1);

        f.setSize(300,100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```